# Defining a block reward contract in Parity Aura consensus

Tags: parity, proof-of-authority, aura

I've been looking at creating a block reward contract for Parity (as documented [here](https://wiki.parity.io/Block-Reward-Contract)).  I'm wondering if I would be able to model a system using this that would send all the wei spent on a transaction back to a central faucet account.

The [interface](https://github.com/parity-contracts/block-reward/blob/master/contracts/BlockReward.sol) for these contracts looks as though it takes a list of accounts and reward types, and allows you to assign static values to send to those accounts, but there's no information available about the gas price/amount that went into that block.  Is that wei just burned, or is it awarded to the block author *in addition* to what the reward contract distributes?